# Drive issues? Bus error (core dumped) and smartctl *and dmesg logs

Tags: smartctl, drive

Troubleshooting a failed archive extraction. Getting a "Bus error (core dumped)". Thinking it may be a possible disk issue so the smartctl output is below - not sure what to make of it.

EDIT: Here's the full output of smartctl -a

```
smartctl 7.1 2020-04-05 r5049 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB
Serial Number:    S251NCAGA00610R
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 870147fd8
Firmware Version: EXM02B6Q
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug 31 07:10:26 2022 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 136) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       80107
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   096   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       194
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6078
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   074   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       6078
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12019862643

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Here are the dmesg logs as well:

```
[5613104.770561] ata8.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[5613104.770973] ata8.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[5613104.771376] ata8.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[5613104.771769] ata8.00: cmd 60/08:98:d0:9d:dd/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 4096 in
                          res 41/40:08:cf:9d:dd/00:00:04:00:00/04 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[5613104.772561] ata8.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[5613104.772956] ata8.00: error: { UNC }
[5613104.773600] ata8.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[5613104.778934] ata8.00: disabling queued TRIM support
[5613104.784338] ata8.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[5613104.789674] ata8.00: disabling queued TRIM support
[5613104.794734] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
[5613104.795280] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[5613104.795706] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[5613104.796115] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[5613104.796524] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 04 dd 9d d0 00 00 08 00
[5613104.796921] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 81632720 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this are highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the full output of `smartctl -a`? Looking at "Power on hours", the disk has been in use for over nine years. It is quite normal that disks fail at this age or even earlier.

Comment: I added the full output of smartctl -a

Comment: the drive should be considered as dead and needs to be replaced